# Creating a list from a string that contains numbers separated by commas; Python 3

Tags: python, list, function

Hi so first I would like to say this is for homework so I do not want to straight answer. The problem is:

> This task will implement the functionality of creating a list from a string that contains numbers separated by commas (with possibly blank space between them). For example the string "1,2,3, 4.5, 6.7, 8" would become the list: [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6.7, 8]. 
> Write the following functions:
>   is_numeric() - This function has a string parameter and returns True if all the characters in the string are digits, comma, space, or dot. If there are any other characters, the function should return False.
>   string_to_list() - This function takes a string parameter and returns the list of the numbers in the string. First it should call the is_numeric() function to check that the string has no bad characters (e.g. letters). If there are any bad characters, it should return the empty list. If there are no bad characters it should try to build the list out of the data in the string. For this it should look at every substring between two consecutive commas. If there is no dot in that substring, then the substring should be converted to an integer. If there is exactly one dot (no more, no less) it should be converted into a float. If any of the substrings between two consecutive commas can not be converted to an int or a float (e.g. "4.5.8" as it has too many dots), the function should still return the empty list. Hint: the split() method may be useful for this task.
>   main() - The main() function that will get a string from the user, it will then call the string_to_list() function to build a list out of the user string and then print the resulting list. It will next ask the user if they want to continue. If they want to continue, they should enter 'y'. In that case the function (main) should repeat the previous steps: ask the user for an input, convert it to a list, ask the user again if they want to continue. And so on until the user does not want to continue, in which case he or she should enter 'n'.

The only piece of code I do have checks only the first letter that is in the string to see if it is a digit or a letter. I need to check whether if there is a letter, number, comma, period, or space. I got really lost reading this program. I know I need to get a string from the user, then make that string into a list if only everything is the string is one of the acceptable inputs (letter, number, comma, period, space) Below is my code so far and what my code will be reading in the shell.

```
s = input("Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:")

def is_numeric(s):
    for char in list(s):
        if char.isdigit():
            return True
        if char.isalpha():
            return False
            break


if is_numeric(s) == True:
    print(s)
else:
    print('Error')
```

> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
> Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:1,2,3,4
>   1,2,3,4
>
> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
> Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:1,2,3,a
>   1,2,3,a
>
> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
> Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:a,1,2,3
>   Error
>
> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
> Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:1234a
>   1234a
>
> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
> Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:asdf3
>   Error

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "The only piece of code I do have checks only the first letter" — if you are aware of that, why haven't you fixed it? You even got the loop there already. Also, try to write the rest of the program with the assumption that ``is_numeric`` is working correctly.

Comment: Remove the "if char.isdigit(): return True" part, and you should get that function correctly. You'll just need to write the parser to parse input separated by comma, then check isnumeric on each partition.

Comment: @Bogdan This is my first experience with For loops and Defining functions, I've tried adding a counter to continue the loop but I just am not having any luck.

Comment: We have not covered parser or parse, so I have no clue what you are talking about lol but thanks @justhalf

Comment: By parser, I meant "lines of code that can separate the input string into a list, containing elements in the input string separated by comma"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't want the loop to return `True` until the end, but you want it to return `False` and break if the test is false. Your loop returns `True` or `False` right on the first iteration, so you don't want the two return statements within the loop. Secondly, you can create a list or string of characters and use it to check whether each character is within that list. In this case, it would be something like `",. "` or `[",", ".", " "]`.

You should write something like this:

```
def is_numeric(s):

    for char in s:
        if not char.isdigit() and char not in [" ", ".", ","]:
            return False

    return True
```

Here, if the character is not a digit, or the character is not in the list `[" ", ".", ","]`, the function returns `False`, which automatically ends the loop. If the loop completes without returning a value, then all the characters meet your criteria and the function goes to the next line and returns `True`.

Edit:

If you want to use a placeholder variable, set it to `True` and write the loop to set it to `False` i f the criteria aren't met. If the loop doesn't modify it, the condition is true for the entire string, so it remains `True`.

```
def is_numeric(s):
    is_digit = True

    for char in s:
        if not char.isdigit() and char not in [" ", ".", ","]:
            is_digit = False
            break

    return is_digit
```

Comment: your code when reading it seems that it will work but when I try to run it, the code doesn't work properly.

Comment: I used `or` instead of `and`, but I cleaned it up and tested it, so this should work.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! When I was first running your code I would enter "a,b,c,d,e" it would return a,b,c,d,e. But now it is working great!

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it by selecting the "check" at the top, thanks!

Comment: do you know how I would go about the second function I need to create?

Comment: Ask another question!

Comment: New question is live! @impossibility

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394388/create-a-function-that-checks-if-a-string-can-be-converted-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Have you talked about regular expressions in your class yet? If so, you are probably expected to be using those. Take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

If not, you are probably expected to make a placeholder variable as true, loop through the entire string checking each character and make your placeholder variable false if bad characters are detected. You shouldn't use the return statement until you've gone through the whole string. (after the loop)

Comment: Hi, we are expected to make the placeholder. Check for bad characters are present, if there are bad characters we will return a blank string. We will not append the string to contain the good characters.

Comment: I meant we will not append the list to contain the good characters.