# Create a function that checks if a string can be converted or not?

Tags: python

I now have a working piece of code that will check if the string is a correct character now I need to check if it can be converted to a list.

This is the prompt:

> string_to_list() - This function takes a string parameter and returns the list of the numbers in the string. First it should call the is_numeric() function to check that the string has no bad characters (e.g. letters). If there are any bad characters, it should return the empty list. If there are no bad characters it should try to build the list out of teh data in the string. For this it should look at every substring between two consecutive commas. If there is no dot in that substring, then the substring should be converted to an integer. If there is exactly one dot (no more, no less) it should be converted into a float. If any of the substrings between two consecutive commas can not be converted to an int or a float (e.g. "4.5.8" as it has too many dots), the function should still return the empty list. Hint: the split() method may be useful for this task.

Code:

```
s = input("Enter a set of numbers (integers or floats) separated by comma:")
L = []

def is_numeric(s):
    is_digit = True

    for char in s:
        if not char.isdigit() and char not in [" ", ".", ","]:
            is_digit = False
            break

    return is_digit
"""
Above checks to see if all the characters in string are good if they are the function is true
"""
def main():  
    if is_numeric(s) == True:
        print(s)
    else:
        print(L)

main()
```

I have the main there just so I could make sure that is_numeric(s) was working properly.

EDIT of adding s.count into a new function

```
def string_to_list():
is_numeric(s) == True
for char in s:
    if s.count(".") >1:
        is_numeric = False
        break
    return is_numeric(s)
```

Comment: Can you use `int()`, `float()` ? Apply this function if it raise ValueError then your string is incorrect return False

Comment: Well when I input lets say "4.5.5" there is no ValueError it just prints it fine. So how would I be able to tell whether the ValueError is happening or now? In my code Im saying if there is a "." then it is fine, now I want to check between the commas to make sure there is only 1 dot.

Comment: sorry. just edit previous comment.

Comment: No I am sure both `float('4.5.5')` and `int('4.5.5')` both raises ValueError try it

Comment: >>> int('4.5.5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    int('4.5.5')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5.5'
>>> int('4.5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int('4.5')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5'
>>> 

You are correct but it also does it for 4.5, which I don't want it to do.

Comment: actually `int('4.5')` raise ValueError but `float('4.5')` not

Comment: yes I just realized where I messed up. Okay but how would I def a function to have this check each of my characters in the string?

Comment: let me think I am also a Python learner only

Comment: Aright thank you, take your time.

Comment: Check if  `s.count(".") <= 1`.

Comment: @user2884569 Not more technique! `eval('4.5')` it raises AttributeError it not a valid number

Comment: okay but '4.5' isn't hardcoded, whatever solution will have to work for a value and a every index.

Comment: @WaleedKhan how would you implement s.count into a new function I tried without any success.. check edit above..